# How to add plugins in WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress.com

I am creating a site and I need to use plugins, but on my dashboard there is nowhere to add my plugins for my site. How do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Wordpress.com** does not allow you to install plugins.

From their [Plugins](http://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/) support page:

> Plugins are tools used to extend the functionality of the WordPress
>   platform. However, they are only applicable to self-hosted blogs and
>   web sites using the WordPress.org software. **Plugins are not permitted
>   here at WordPress.com** for various security reasons.
>
> ...
>
> **If you require plugins, you’ll need to acquire your own hosting.**

Comment: then can i attach my site for free on wordpress if i build the site by own hosting.

Comment: If use Wordpress.com online service you can't install plugins. If you buy a hosting and install on it Wordpress, you can install any plugins. Look at the link in my answer to find more info.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install plugins on wordpress.com. You have to create a WordPress Site with the software offered on wordpress.org.

If you don't know how to install WordPress, I would recommend to choose a Managed WordPress Hosting like [MyWoHo](http://mywoho.com), [Wpengine](http://wpengine.com) or Websynthesis. MyWoHo starts at 3$/month. It's not much, if you wanto to try.

Comment: If you are affiliated with the site, please disclose that in your answer.